# change links color with toggle a slider button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i made a slider button to change the color of body and links when i toggle that. color of body successfully changed. but i don't know how to change the links color with toggle the button. i tried to solve problem with codes below but it dose not work so i wrote the code for body not links. please help me . thank you.
here is sample codes:

in java script:

```js
    function myFunction(){
    var element = document.body;
    element.classlist.toggle("change");
    }
```

```css
    .body{
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .change{
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
    }
    
    //making slider button
    .switch {
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 35px;
      height: 22px;
    }
    
    .switch input { 
      opacity: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
    }
    
    .slider {
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: #ccc;
      -webkit-transition: .4s;
      transition: .4s;
    }
    
    .slider:before {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      height: 18px;
      width: 18px;
      left: 2px;
      bottom: 2px;
      background-color: white;
      -webkit-transition: .4s;
      transition: .4s;
    }
    
    input:checked + .slider {
      background-color: #2196F3;
    }
    
    input:focus + .slider {
      box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
    }
    
    input:checked + .slider:before {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(13px);
      -ms-transform: translateX(13px);
      transform: translateX(13px);
    }
    
    /* Rounded sliders */
    .slider.round {
      border-radius: 34px;
    }
    
    .slider.round:before {
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
    <a href="#">this is a link</a>
    </div>
    
    <div>
    some text...
    </div>
    
    <label class=".switch">
     <input type="checkbox" onClick="myFunction">
     <span class="slider round">&nbsp;</span>
    </label>
```

Comment: Please tell more about your problem

Comment: element.class`L`ist